# select disabled not passing selected value to the php code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having a one page activity code, where I can submit a new data and fetch the previous data on the same page. Whenever i fetch the data i mark select disable by js code. But the fetched data will not submitted to database, because it is disabled. I want to save the data of disabled dropdown.

```
 <input type="hidden" name='same_as_select' value=""/>
```

JS Code :

```
 function getData(val)
 {
 var myLength = $("#mob_1").val();
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "test.php",
 dataType: "json",
 data:'dt='+val,
 success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
 var len = data.length;
 if(len > 0){
   var id12 = data[0]['id12'];
   var id13 = data[0]['id13'];
   document.getElementById('category').value = id12;
   document.getElementById('source').value = id13;
   if(id13!='DID NOT PROVIDE')
   {
    $('#source').attr("disabled", "disabled").value; 
    $('#category').attr("disabled", "disabled").value; 
    }
   else
    {
    $('#source').removeAttr("disabled"); 
    $('#category').removeAttr("disabled");
    document.getElementById('category').value = '';
    document.getElementById('source').value = '';
    }
   }
   }
   });
   }
```

HTML:

```
 <input type="number" name="mob_1" ID='mob_1' value="" onchange="getData(this.value);" />
 <select name="category" id="category">
 <option value="" class="1">--SELECT--</option>
 <option value="NEWSPAPER">NEWSPAPER</option>
 <option value="ONLINE">ONLINE</option>
 </select>  
 <select name="source" id="category">
 <option value="" class="1">--SELECT--</option>
  //THIS SOURCE COMING FROM DATABASE BY CATEGORY SELECTION
 </select>
```

In php query it shows category='',source='' because it is disabled

Comment: This is the default behavior of a html field. The field doesn't exist nor submitted when it is set as disabled. An alternate is to use readonly, instead of disable.

Comment: according to html behavior readonly not work for dropdown

Comment: @Don'tDownVote show me the answer. you mark it as duplicate but i didn't find any suitable answer which solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have two different elements with the same ID (*category*) - fix it.

Second, to get the data from the disabled selection boxes use the following (here is example for the category selection):

```
var categorySelection= document.getElementById('category')
var categoryValue = categorySelection.options[categorySelection.selectedIndex].value;
```

and use `categoryValue` where you need to.

Comment: but how to use this variable in  php

Comment: @Shalini the `categoryValue` contains a string with the selected value. Just append it to the variable you are sending to the PHP side (the `data` variable).

Comment: can you please elaborate, i can't understand.